# Accessing existing Windows environment variables from WSL

Tags: bash, windows-10, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to access existing Windows environment variables such as USERPROFILE from withing the WSL bash prompt. There is information from Microsoft on the use of WSLENV [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/22/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/), and I have tried to work with this:

I added `WSLENV` as a new System variable within the usual Windows "Environment Variables" control panel, setting it to `USERPROFILE/u`. I then open Ubuntu from the taskbar, and type:

```
$ echo $USERPROFILE
```

...but nothing is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a workaround for ya.

```
$ /mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C "echo %OS%"
Windows_NT
$ tmpvar=`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C "echo %OS%"`
$ echo $tmpvar
Windows_NT
```

I haven't checked `WSLENV` but the upper one should work. Far from being elegant though.

Answer (score 6):

Improved Gábor's answer, since as I've discovered it had a small bug, variables obtained that way contain invisible carriage return character, that could cause unexpected issues latter.
Here is Example:

```
$ cd /mnt/c/
$ mkdir Windows_NT
$ tmpvar=`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C "echo %OS%"`
$ echo $tmpvar
Windows_NT
```

All seems to be ok, but no:

```
$ cd $tmpvar
: No such file or directory
```

This is because **tmpvar** variable contains additional carriage return character (aka **^M** or **\r**) at the end. We can check this via ls command:

```
$ ls -ld $tmpvar
ls: cannot access 'Windows_NT'$'\r': No such file or directory
```

In order to remove that character, output could be be additionally processed with **sed** or **tr**:

```
tmpvar=$(cmd.exe /C echo %OS%|sed $'s/\r$//')
```

or

```
tmpvar=$(cmd.exe /C echo %OS%|tr -d '\r')
```

*I've also simplified command a bit. Path /mnt/c/Windows/System32 is already included in $PATH WSL variable by default in recent Windows 10 updates, so just **cmd.exe** should work.*

Now, **ls** and **cd** commands work without errors:

```
$ ls -ld $tmpvar
drwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 512 Feb 12 05:38 Windows_NT
$ cd $tmpvar
$ pwd
/mnt/c/Windows_NT
```

**pwd** command confirms that current directory is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As this question is from early 2018, my first thought is that the Windows 10 build @user2023370 used was not yet 17063.

Other things to point out:

- When setting environment variables from the control panel, make sure that the WSL process is not already running.
- Because the USERPROFILE environment variable is a path, you need to add the `/p` option:

```
  WSLENV=USERPROFILE/up
```

To test how `/p` option affects the passed variable, try this in cmd.exe:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\arttu>set WSLENV=USERPROFILE/up

C:\Users\arttu>wsl

$ echo $USERPROFILE
/mnt/c/Users/arttu

$ exit
logout

C:\Users\arttu>set WSLENV=USERPROFILE/u

C:\Users\arttu>wsl

$ echo $USERPROFILE
C:\Users\arttu
```